# Watir-Webdriver, Ruby - click on the table row

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'm using Watir-Webdriver and Ruby. On the page I have a table of record. I need to click on any row and it should go the next page. How can I click on the row?
Here's the source code for each record from the table

```html
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-click="clickHandler({rowItem: item})" ng-repeat="item in ngModel">
<td class="ng-bindging">Sometext</td>
<td class="ng-bindging">Sometext1</td>
<td class="ng-bindging">Sometext2</td>
<td class="ng-bindging">Sometext3</td>
<td class="ng-bindging">Sometext4</td>
<td>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
</td>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you do not care which `tr` element you click, you could simply click the first `tr` element in the table:

```
record_table = browser.table
record_table.tr.click
```

If the first row is a header row, you might need to click the last row instead:

```
record_table = browser.table
record_table.trs.last.click
```

Note that `browser.table` will click the first table on the page. If there are more tables on the page, you will want to be more specific - eg `browser.table(id: 'some_id')`.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use your example.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to find unique attributes that Watir can access. The first issue is that your angular app doesn't product valid html5 without `data-` prepended.

I don't know what your other rows look like to know how to click this one versus another one, but if that attribute is unique, you could use css:

`browser.element(css: "tr[ng-repeat='item in ngModel']")`

If your text is unique you could also do this (even though it is less ideal):

`browser.td(text: 'Sometext').parent`